# TortoiseGit - Change font size of Commit and Diff windows

Tags: font-size, tortoisegit

OS - Windows 11,
TortoiseGit 2.15.0.0

I want to increase font size of TortoiseGit Commit and Diff windows

I tried updating the font size
In Tortoise Git > Settings > For below configurations, i updated font size to 13

- Dialogs 1,
- TortoiseGitBlame and
- TortoiseGitUDiff.

But its not reflecting.

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug with TortoiseGit's developers - we can't really help you here.